# How can I get tmux to ignore commands when inside a neovim pane?

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm trying to get my tmux and neovim to work together as seamlessly as possible. There's kinda one issue I'm having with it though. Whenever I'm in a neovim pane within tmux, and I want to split neovim into horizontal/vertical windows with the default desired bind...

`C-w v` for vertical

`C-w n` or `C-w s` for horizontal.

<s>It just plain hits or misses. Its not very responsive...</s>
**EDIT:**
Now noticing that it is responsive, but I have to press `C-w` twice before I hit `s` for it to only activate in neovim. Why? I don't want that behavior

Whenever I do that with the `C-w s` for instance and only hit `C-w` once then `s` , it triggers the tmux command to switch between any available sessions. I only want it to do that when I'm in a tmux pane. When in neovim I want it to split. My tmux prefix is `C-w` and I want to keep as such, but how can I get tmux to ignore commands when I'm in my neovim pane. I don't want to change anymore default binds.

**UPDATE 4/4 /2020: **

```
# eliminates delay when switching out of mode in vim/nvim
set -sg escape-time 0

# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-w
bind C-w send-prefix

# Easy config reload
bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "tmux.conf reloaded."

unbind '"'
unbind %

# vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

bind 'v' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w v'  'split-window -h'
bind 's' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w n'  'split-window -v'
bind 'n' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w n' 'split-window -v'

bind 'h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w h'  'select-pane -L'
bind 'j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w j'  'select-pane -D'
bind 'k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w k'  'select-pane -U'
bind 'l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w l'  'select-pane -R'
bind '\' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w \'  'select-pane -l'

bind 'S-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w S-h'
bind 'S-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w S-j'
bind 'S-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w S-k'
bind 'S-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w S-l'
```

Decided to go back with the `vim-tmux-navigator plugin`, but I'm having one last issue...I'm not quite sure how can I script neovim's window shifting bind. The bind goes `C-w` then `Shift-<direction>`. The last 4 commands in my `.tmux.conf` is my attempt at it, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vim/neovim by default uses the prefix `C-w` for window movement and rotation, and I changed my prefix for tmux to `C-w` as well. With that in mind in order for me to get tmux to recognize I'm in a neovim pane, I would have to hit `C-w` twice to just ignore tmux and execute my commands in vim/neovim.

However, this is way too much overhead for my liking...

With the help of [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) with some slight changes I was able to use the default `C-w` for window movement. The plugin allows you to move from your vim/neovim windows(panes) to tmux panes seamlessly. The plugin by default maps pane movement without the need of `C-w` with `C-<hjkl>`. I'm so use to hitting `C-w` I changed it back to the default... In my `.vimrc` or `init.vim` if you're using neovim, I added this for the plugin...

```
let g:tmux_navigator_no_mappings = 1

nnoremap <silent> <c-w>h :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-w>j :TmuxNavigateDown<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-w>k :TmuxNavigateUp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-w>l :TmuxNavigateRight<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-w>\ :TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>
```

In my `.tmux.conf` I added this

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-w
bind C-w send-prefix

# vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

bind 'h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w h'  'select-pane -L'
bind 'j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w j'  'select-pane -D'
bind 'k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w k'  'select-pane -U'
bind 'l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w l'  'select-pane -R'
bind '\' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w \'  'select-pane -l'
```

To check if you're in a vim/neovim pane to split, else split in tmux. I did this...

```
bind 'v' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w v'  'split-window -h'
bind 's' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w n'  'split-window -v'
bind 'n' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w n' 'split-window -v'
```

For shifting panes with the shift key I made the mistake of thinking I should use `S-<hjkl>`, when in reality all S is doing is capitalizing a letter. With that in mind instead of doing for ex, `C-w S-h` I did this...

```
bind 'H' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w H'
bind 'J' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w J' 
bind 'K' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w K' 
bind 'L' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w L'
```

If you're wondering why I omitted the `C-w` in the scripts, its because by default the prefix is needed anyways unless I use `bind -n`

Answer (score 3):

It isn't clear if you have already tried to configure tmux to do this and it isn't working or if you are asking how to do it.

Anyway, usually this is done by changing the required key bindings to only execute on some condition, for example you might check for neovim:

```
bind v if -F '#{!=:#{pane_current_command},neovim}' 'splitw -v' 'send v'
```

Or for choose-tree:

```
bind s if -F '#{!=:#{pane_current_command},neovim}' 'choose-tree -Zs' 'send s'
```

You can use a different condition if you would prefer to check something different than `pane_current_command` see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Formats and the `FORMATS` section in the man page.

You will need to do this for every key binding you want to be passed to neovim when it is running in the active pane.

You could do it in for them all in one go by using key tables which would be shorter but is more fiddly to configure.

Comment: I update my question and made some edits 

I changed it to this `bind v if -F '#{!=:#{pane_current_command},nvim}' 'splitw -v' 'send'`
Since `nvim` is the command to run neovim in the terminal. Using `neovim` in the `.conf` still splits tmux even when I am in the neovim pane. When I change that line to `nvim` however, it doesn't trigger tmux...But it also doesn't trigger the window splitting I want. Idk what I'm doing wrong, I reloaded my `.conf`

Comment: Run neovim in one pane then do `tmux lsp -F'#{pane_current_command}'` in another pane - whatever this shows for the neovim pane is what you want to have in the comparison. My example is slightly wrong - you should `send` the key you want to send to neovim, so it should be `send v` or `send s` not just `send`. I'll edit it.

Comment: The `tmux lsp -F'#{pane_current_command}'` in a tmux pane returns `tmux`. How can I do that in a `neovim` pane ? I tried using the `:!` but that doesn't seem to work. I get `E499: Empty file  for '%' or '#', only works with "p:h"`

Comment: No, run neovim in one pane and run the `tmux lsp ...` in a *different* pane in the same window, then it will show a line for each pane - one with tmux and one with nvim or neovim or whatever.

Comment: I get `tmux` and `nvim` as the output, but the commands u posted don't work at all...Even when I change `neovim` to `nvim`. It ignores tmux pane splitting which is what I want, but it doesn't split the windows in neovim for whatever reason.

Comment: Did you change `send` to `send v` like I said? Does `v` split the window in neovim?

Comment: I decided to go back to using the vim-tmux-navigator plugin and got it to work, but I'm having one last issue. May you please help me ?

Comment: I don't know anything about plugins, sorry.

Comment: I figured it out, I'll post the answer. Thank you so much!